# Compilation errors while compiling V8 engine on Windows 10 with MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compilation, windows-10, v8

First of all, I run next command:

```
python tools/dev/v8gen.py x64.release.sample
```

All GN files generating successfuly. After that I run following command:

```
ninja -C out.gn/x64.release.sample v8_monolith
```

After several minutes of compilation, I receive a lot of compilation error:

```
[226/1842] LINK bytecode_builtins_list_generator.exe bytecode_builtins_list_generator.exe.pdb
FAILED: bytecode_builtins_list_generator.exe bytecode_builtins_list_generator.exe.pdb
..\..\third_party\llvm-build\Release+Asserts\bin\lld-link.exe /OUT:./bytecode_builtins_list_generator.exe /nologo -libpath:..\..\third_party\llvm-build\Release+Asserts\lib\clang\15.0.0\lib\windows "-libpath:../../../Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.31.31103/ATLMFC/lib/x64" "-libpath:../../../Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.31.31103/lib/x64" "-libpath:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64" "-libpath:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x64" "-libpath:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.19041.0\\um\x64" /MACHINE:X64  /PDB:./bytecode_builtins_list_generator.exe.pdb @./bytecode_builtins_list_generator.exe.rsp
lld-link: error: procedure symbol record for `_CxxThrowException` in d:\a01\_work\43\s\Intermediate\vctools\libvcruntime.nativeproj_520857879\objr\amd64\throw.obj refers to PDB item index 0x134F which is not a valid function ID record
lld-link: error: procedure symbol record for `_IsExceptionObjectToBeDestroyed` in d:\a01\_work\43\s\Intermediate\vctools\libvcruntime.nativeproj_520857879\objr\amd64\ehhelpers.obj refers to PDB item index 0x1193 which is not a valid function ID record
lld-link: error: procedure symbol record for `__FrameUnwindFilter` in d:\a01\_work\43\s\Intermediate\vctools\libvcruntime.nativeproj_520857879\objr\amd64\ehhelpers.obj refers to PDB item index 0x118E which is not a valid function ID record
lld-link: error: procedure symbol record for `__std_terminate` in d:\a01\_work\43\s\Intermediate\vctools\libvcruntime.nativeproj_520857879\objr\amd64\ehhelpers.obj refers to PDB item index 0x1190 which is not a valid function ID record
lld-link: error: procedure symbol record for `_CallSETranslator<__FrameHandler3>` in d:\a01\_work\43\s\Intermediate\vctools\libvcruntime.nativeproj_520857879\objr\amd64\risctrnsctrl.obj refers to PDB item index 0x12F7 which is not a valid function ID record
lld-link: error: procedure symbol record for `_CallSETranslator<__FrameHandler4>` in d:\a01\_work\43\s\Intermediate\vctools\libvcruntime.nativeproj_520857879\objr\amd64\risctrnsctrl.obj refers to PDB item index 0x12F8 which is not a valid function ID record
lld-link: error: procedure symbol record for `FH4::DecompFuncInfo` in d:\a01\_work\43\s\Intermediate\vctools\libvcruntime.nativeproj_520857879\objr\amd64\risctrnsctrl.obj refers to PDB item index 0x1151 which is not a valid function ID record
lld-link: error: procedure symbol record for `__FrameHandler3::ExecutionInCatch` in d:\a01\_work\43\s\Intermediate\vctools\libvcruntime.nativeproj_520857879\objr\amd64\risctrnsctrl.obj refers to PDB item index 0x12EC which is not a valid function ID record
lld-link: error: procedure symbol record for `__FrameHandler4::ExecutionInCatch` in d:\a01\_work\43\s\Intermediate\vctools\libvcruntime.nativeproj_520857879\objr\amd64\risctrnsctrl.obj refers to PDB item index 0x12DF which is not a valid function ID record
lld-link: error: procedure symbol record for `__FrameHandler4::FrameUnwindToEmptyState` in d:\a01\_work\43\s\Intermediate\vctools\libvcruntime.nativeproj_520857879\objr\amd64\risctrnsctrl.obj refers to PDB item index 0x12E2 which is not a valid function ID record
lld-link: error: procedure symbol record for `__FrameHandler3::GetEstablisherFrame` in d:\a01\_work\43\s\Intermediate\vctools\libvcruntime.nativeproj_520857879\objr\amd64\risctrnsctrl.obj refers to PDB item index 0x12F0 which is not a valid function ID record
lld-link: error: procedure symbol record for `__FrameHandler3::GetRangeOfTrysToCheck` in d:\a01\_work\43\s\Intermediate\vctools\libvcruntime.nativeproj_520857879\objr\amd64\risctrnsctrl.obj refers to PDB item index 0x12F6 which is not a valid function ID record
lld-link: error: procedure symbol record for `__FrameHandler3::UnwindNestedFrames` in d:\a01\_work\43\s\Intermediate\vctools\libvcruntime.nativeproj_520857879\objr\amd64\risctrnsctrl.obj refers to PDB item index 0x12F1 which is not a valid function ID record
lld-link: error: procedure symbol record for `__FrameHandler4::UnwindNestedFrames` in d:\a01\_work\43\s\Intermediate\vctools\libvcruntime.nativeproj_520857879\objr\amd64\risctrnsctrl.obj refers to PDB item index 0x12E3 which is not a valid function ID record
lld-link: error: procedure symbol record for `_CreateFrameInfo` in d:\a01\_work\43\s\Intermediate\vctools\libvcruntime.nativeproj_520857879\objr\amd64\risctrnsctrl.obj refers to PDB item index 0x12DD which is not a valid function ID record
lld-link: error: procedure symbol record for `_GetThrowImageBase` in d:\a01\_work\43\s\Intermediate\vctools\libvcruntime.nativeproj_520857879\objr\amd64\risctrnsctrl.obj refers to PDB item index 0x12EB which is not a valid function ID record
lld-link: error: procedure symbol record for `_SetImageBase` in d:\a01\_work\43\s\Intermediate\vctools\libvcruntime.nativeproj_520857879\objr\amd64\risctrnsctrl.obj refers to PDB item index 0x12DB which is not a valid function ID record
lld-link: error: procedure symbol record for `_SetThrowImageBase` in d:\a01\_work\43\s\Intermediate\vctools\libvcruntime.nativeproj_520857879\objr\amd64\risctrnsctrl.obj refers to PDB item index 0x12FB which is not a valid function ID record
lld-link: error: procedure symbol record for `__vcrt_getptd` in d:\a01\_work\43\s\Intermediate\vctools\libvcruntime.nativeproj_520857879\objr\amd64\per_thread_data.obj refers to PDB item index 0x1270 which is not a valid function ID record
lld-link: error: procedure symbol record for `__FrameHandler3::GetCurrentState` in d:\a01\_work\43\s\Intermediate\vctools\libvcruntime.nativeproj_520857879\objr\amd64\ehstate.obj refers to PDB item index 0x12F2 which is not a valid function ID record
lld-link: error: too many errors emitted, stopping now (use /errorlimit:0 to see all errors)
[235/1842] CXX obj/torque_base/implementation-visitor.obj
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

What could be causing this problem? How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem, and I solved it like this:

1. Download the visual studio 2019 installer, and install vs2019, notice that no need to check the Windows SDK item as it's not the point and no need to reinstall/add a new version of Windows SDK. And, vs2019 could exists along with vs2022.
2. Switch to vs2019 compile environment: Open a new Windows Terminal tab, and execute command:

```
> set vs2019_install=[path to your \Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community]
> set WINDOWSSDKDIR=[path to your \Windows Kits\10]
> set DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0
> gclient sync
```

3. OK, you could build v8 with vs2019 now:

```
> python tools\dev\gm.py x64.release
```

Hope this helps.